# error procedure or function mysql not found

Tags: c#, mysql

```
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("sp_data", connection);
cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
MySqlDataReader rdrdata = cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

error : Procedure or function '`sp_data`' cannot be found in database

Answer (score 17):

Just ensure that you have set your DB name in your connection string in lower case.

Comment: @Farshid this worked. What is the reason behind this? This sounds ridiculous.

Comment: Any idea why is this even a thing? I spent so much time trying to debug and found that this change made all the difference?? My DB name is mixed case.

Answer (score 1):

Found that my database was in upper case in the connection string but the Actual name was in the lower case. corrected this and worked perfect

Answer (score 0):

It may happen that you try to pass parameters to procedure in some wrong way. This answer is not relevant but might help someone.
For Example

```
command = new MySqlCommand("checkUser", con);
                    command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    //command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userName", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = user.getName();
                    //command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pass", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = user.getPassword();
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userName", user.getName()) ;
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pass", user.getPassword());
```

commented lines gave me error.

Answer (score 0):

Check that your MySql.Data library is the same or lower than your MySql DB version. In my case, MySql.Data 8.0.21 wasn't backwards compatible with innodb 8.0.19.

You can check your MySql DB version with this query:

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE "%version%";
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this and turns out it was permissions. Modify to suit your database:

```
GRANT EXECUTE ON `database`.* TO 'user'@'localhost';
GRANT EXECUTE ON `database.%`.* TO 'user'@'localhost';
GRANT EXECUTE ON `database.*`.* TO 'user'@'localhost';
-- etc...
```

Double and triple check those permissions! I just wish the error was more informative...

Answer (score 0):

The syntax needed to find a procedure/function is the following:

```
[databaseName].[procedureName]
```

For example:

```
database.sp_data
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).